# Using mypy with with lazy initialization of instance attributes

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

**UPDATE**: trying to check/fill values in another function

---

I'm trying to use mypy in my projects, but many of the instance attributes I use are only initialized after `__init__`, and not inside it. However, I do want to keep the good practice of declaring all instance attributes at `__init__`, so I need some complicated solutions to make this work.

An example to how I want this to behave (currently mypy is complaining):

```
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y: int = None  # will initialize later, but I know it will be an int

    def fill_values(self):
        self.y = x**2

    def do(self) -> int:
        return self.x + self.y
```

Currently mypy complains about the assignment of `self.y`, and wants it to be `Optional` or `None`.

If I agree with it and change the line to `self.y: Optional[int] = None`, then mypy complains on the return value of `do`, because `self.y` might be `None`.

The only way I found around it is to add as assert before using `self.y`, like: `assert self.y is not None`, which mypy picks up and understands. However, starting each method with many asserts is quite hard. I have many such values, and usually one method that initializes all of them, and all other methods runs after it.

I understand that mypy is rightfully complaining (the method `do` can be called before `fill_values`), but even when I try to prevent it I can't get mypy to accept this. I can extend this example by adding more functionality but mypy can't infer this:

```
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y: int = None  # will initialize later, but I know it will be an int

    def fill_values(self):
        self.y = x**2

    def check_values(self):
        assert self.y is not None

    def do(self) -> int:
        if self.y is None:
            self.fill_values()
        self.check_values()
        return self.x + self.y
```

Any idea of a more elegant solution that multiple assert statements and `Optional` types which obscure the code?

Comment: If there's no reasonable default for `self.y`, what would you do if `do` was called before `fill_values`? You probably would want to pass this decision back up to where it was being called, by perhaps raising an exception?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect that option, but mypy is still complaining

Comment: You can ignore the wrong assignment via a trailing `# type: ignore[assignment]` comment, or you can turn this behaviour off completely by passing [`--no-implicit-optional`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-no-implicit-optional), but you'll loose the none-checks in the situations like @dspencer described. As for validation of optionals: `mypy` only understands direct assertions, not when you put them in a separate method as the inference becomes too cumbersome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found this to work for me:

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self, x: int):
    self.x = x
    self.y: int # Give self.y a type but no value

def fill_values(self):
    self.y = self.x**2

def do(self) -> int:
    return self.x + self.y
```

Essentially all you are doing is telling mypy that `self.y` will be an integer when (and if) it is initialised. Trying to call `self.y` before it is initialised will raise an error and you can check if it has been initialised using `hasattr(self, "y")`.

Comment: That's brilliant! it also solves the issue of "communicating" that `self.y` is eventually gonna be part of the class without actually initializing it.

Comment: Any reason this is not working with `mypy==0.982` and `python 3.9`? MyPy still complains

Comment: @zerohedge this is most likely due to a change to mypy. Try an older version of mypy. See if you can figure out the exact version where this behaviour changed and check the release notes for that version.

Comment: it should be `self.y = self.x**2`